# Multiple parameters psycopg2 where clause - Syntax error

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.7, psycopg2

I get a syntax error at or near the WHERE clause in the last query below.

The query immediately before it with only one parameter works fine, so I am guessing the error has to do with the fact that I am trying to pass two parameters.

Thanks in advance.

```
cur.execute('''SELECT street_name, id FROM tablename 
            WHERE (((suburb = '') IS NOT FALSE) 
            AND ((street_name2 = '') IS NOT FALSE));''')

datesfrompdf = cur.fetchall()
for rowdate, rowid in datesfrompdf:
    cur.execute("DELETE FROM tablename WHERE id = %s;", (rowid + 1,)  #this works fine

    cur.execute('''INSERT INTO tablename (got_date)
                VALUES (%s) WHERE ((suburb IS NOT NULL)     #syntax error here
                AND (street_name2 IS NOT NULL)
                AND (id > %s));''', (rowdate, rowid))
```

Running psql 9.3.14, python 2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot put a `WHERE` clause into an `INSERT` statement - insert inserts new rows. You are probably looking for the `UPDATE` statement.

I can only guess, but you might want something like this:

```
UPDATE tablename 
    SET got_date = (%s)
    WHERE ((suburb IS NOT NULL)
        AND (street_name2 IS NOT NULL)
        AND (id > %s));
```

Comment: Should have picked that up from the documentation. Thanks mate.